# automatically run jenkins job when bitbucket push doesn't before first manually run

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to create pipeline job on jenkins and now i got an issue.
When i create a new branch on my git repository i automatically got a new job on jenkins. I would like to run this job when i push something on the linked branch.

For now on jenkins i have :

```
  triggers {
    bitbucketPush()
  }
```

and on bitbucket :

```
https://MY_JENKINS_LINK/bitbucket-hook/
```

But for now i need to run my job manually once before to get it trigger by bitbucket push. Do you have any idea?

Comment: did you add the jenkins webhook to your bitbucket repository?

Comment: yes this is my webhook https://MY_JENKINS_LINK/bitbucket-hook/. As i said it work after first manual run

Comment: checkout this https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-Server-integration-with-jenkins/qaq-p/307023

Comment: doesn't work for me